# Make polygon appear as point when zooming out beyond set range in ArcGIS Online

Tags: polygon, point, arcgis-online

Is it possible to have a polygon layer visually appear as a point when zooming out beyond a certain extent that i will determine in a web map in ArcGIS Online? 
Or do i have to add a different layer with a point of the center of the polygon and  using the visibility range for each layer have the polygon appear after the point disappears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this is not possible. You will want to set this with the layer in the web map twice and use scale ranges to swap out the centroid styled polygons with the other one.

Comment: Thank you that is how i already solved the problem, maybe they will add this feature in the future.

Comment: I work on that team, currently no set plans for this to be in an upcoming release but I would recommend posting this on ArcGIS Ideas on GeoNet or up-voting if the topic already exists.